# Converting bits to string (data)

Tags: python-3.x

I have file which contains some data (text copied and pasted from the "What You Will Learn" portion of [this PDF](https://www.cisco.com/web/strategy/docs/gov/cis13090_sdn_sled_white_paper.pdf)). Firstly, I have converted the contents in the file to bits successfully. However, when I try to convert it back to the original format, some of the characters are not correctly converted, as shown below:

> Cisco has 
>   developed the Cisco Open Network Environment (ONE)
>   architecture as a multifaceted approach to network
>   programmability delivered across three pillars:
>   ??)É¥ Í?Ð½??ÁÁ±¥?Ñ¥½¸ÁÉ½É?µµ¥¹?¥¹Ñ?É???Ì?¡A%Ì¤?)?áÁ½Í??¥É?Ñ±ä½¸ÍÝ¥Ñ¡?Ì?¹É½ÕÑ?ÉÌÑ¼?Õµ?¹Ð?)?á¥ÍÑ¥¹?=Á?¹±½ÜÍÁ?¥?¥?Ñ¥½¹Ì* ¤&öGV7F?öâ×&VG?÷VäfÆ÷r6öçG&öÆÆW"æB÷VäfÆ÷r ¦vVçG0¨?HÝZ]HÙ??ÙXÝÈÈ[]?\??\X[Ý?\?^\Ë?\X[?Ù\?XÙ\Ë[??\ÛÝ\?ÙHÜ?Ú\Ý?][Û?Ø\X?[]Y\È[?H?]HÙ[

As you can see here some characters are converted successfully, others are not.

My code is below:

```
file = open("test.txt",'r')
myfile = ''.join(map(str,file))
l = []
for i in myfile:
  asc11 = ord(i)
  b = "{0:08b}".format(asc11)
  l.extend(int(y) for y in b)

string_bin = ''.join(map(str,l))
mydata = ''.join(chr(int(string_bin[i:i+8], 2)) for i in range(0,len(string_bin), 8))
print(mydata)
```

What wrong with my code? What I need to change to make it work properly?

Comment: It is not clear what you're trying to accomplish or whether your text file contained ASCII text to begin with.

Comment: I think I was clear about the text, I have provided the link and I mentioned which part I have taken there "What You Will Learn" . My aim is to learn about conversion from binary to string. The code is working for some contents but some are getting unrecognized like what I mentioned above. So I am wondering what I should adjust to make it work properly

Comment: You weren't very clear at all. For instance, what does this mean 'Firstly, I have converted the contents in the file to bits successfully.'? Also, again, a plain text file would not require any kind of convoluted munging at all, you can just call `read` or `readlines` on it and be done.

Comment: Have you looked https://www.cisco.com/web/strategy/docs/gov/cis13090_sdn_sled_white_paper.pdf link????! It contains part called "What You Will Learn"? I have taken this part and created file called test.txt and put that part from that link in the test.txt. Then I have converted all that part into binary? Now when I try to convert the binary into the same content before conversion to binary, some contents converted back as you can see above others are unrecognized.

Comment: the title (*"Converting bits to string (data)"*) has nothing to do with your actual problem: read text from a file in Python (and perhaps also an unrelated problem: extract text from pdf). If `test.txt` is correct then *all you need* (to get the text) is to pass the correct `encoding` parameter to `open()` and remove the rest of your code e.g.: `print(open("test.txt", encoding='utf-8').read())`

Answer (score 1):

## What's Going On?

You are running into an encoding issue because some characters in the PDF are non-ASCII characters. For example, the bullet points are `U+2022` which require [**3 bytes** of storage](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2022/index.htm).

When Python reads from your file, it doesn't know what encoding you used to write that data. Thus it reads `bytes` from the file and uses a character encoding to translate them into `str`s which are stored using Python's own internal unicode format. (This differs from Python 2 where `open()` returned raw bytes stored in a `str` which you could then manually decoded to `unicode`.)

Thus, in Python 3, `open()` accepts a named `encoding` parameter. For example `open("test.txt",'r', encoding='ascii')`. Because you don't specify the encoding when you call `open()`, you end up using your **system's default encoding**. For instance, on my laptop, the default encoding is CP1252 (LATIN-1). Yours may differ.

Whatever encoding Python uses to interpret your file, it then internally uses it's own unicode format to store your string. This means that **your string may internally use mutli-byte characters even if the original encoding did not**. For example, my laptop uses CP1252 to interpret `U+2022` as `â€¢` which is internally stored as `U+00e2`, `U+20AC` and `U+00A2` -- `€` is stored using a multi-byte character even though it was just one byte in the original file.

Let's assume you computer is sane and uses UTF-8 by default (this explanation is similar for many multi-byte characters). When you reach a bullet point, it is stored as `U+2022`. When you call `ord('\u2022')` the result is `8226`. When you then call `"{0:08b}".format(8226)` this returns `"10000000100010"`. That's a **14 character** string. Your parsing code assumes all of the ordinals will generate **8 character** strings. Because of this, the "binary" output becomes misaligned. This means that when you then parse the binary string in 8-character segments, it gets thrown off and starts interpreting things as control characters and all sorts of foreign language characters.

If you call `open(..., encoding='ascii')`, Python will actually throw an exception because it reads non-valid ASCII characters.

## Possible Solutions

I'm not sure why exactly you are converting the input string into the representation that you are using. It's not binary, as your question title would suggest. Rather, you've converted the data into a textual representation of it's binary encoding.

Technically speaking, when you store encoded text to a file, it's stored using a binary representation. Python, and any text editor, has to decode those bytes into it's internal character representation before it can display them as text. Thus, calling `open("test.txt", "r", encoding="utf-8")` reads the binary data out of your text file and converts it into Python's internal unicode format. Similarly, calling `myfile.encode('utf-8')` will return the UTF-8 encoded `bytes` which can then be written to a file, network socket, *etc*.

If, however, you do need to use a format similar to what you are currently using, first, I still recommend you specify an encoding when you call `open()` (I recommend UTF-8). Then you can consider these options:

1. Detect and omit non-ASCII characters. They will have an ordinal >= 128.
2. Mimic UTF-16 or UTF-32 and output multi-byte output for all characters. For example, use `"{0:032b}".format(asc11)` and then parse the result in 32-character chunks. It's memory and storage inefficient, but it will preserve multi-byte characters.

Regardless, I highly recommend reading the [Dive Into Python 3 chapter about strings](http://www.diveintopython3.net/strings.html).